# WooCommerce "Error processing checkout. Please try again". How do I get more details?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am writing (actually modifying an existing one) gift card plugin. During checkout, the gift cards are created on a different system through a Web JSON API.

The problem is, once I activate the modified plugin, I get "Error processing checkout. Please try again" when I click "Proceed to Payment". Obviously this has nothing to do with the payment gateway. In fact I am using coupons to make the total amount 0, so there's no payment involved.

So the question is, how can I get a more descriptive error message, so that I can track down the code causing an error?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the fatal error logs? WooCommerce does try to capture fatals so ou might check WooCommerce -> Status -> Logs and see if any beginning with the word fatal appear in the dropdown. If so select it and view.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my code was `echo`ing an error message and then exiting (`exit(1)`), which would then get forwarded to the front-end, which was expecting a JSON response (AJAX), hene the error message. In other words, that was a front-end error message.

To find out, I monitored the API call using Chrome DevTools.